# In .net why is throwing an exception computationally heavy?

Tags: .net

In .net why is throwing an exception computationally heavy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things like computing the full call stack at the exception point take time and computation.

However, there is some places where .NET does better than C++, since it doesn't have to track memory that needs to be cleaned up the same way as a C++ exception handler.

For some more details, I'd recommend [Rico Mariani's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2003/12/19/44697.aspx) on this subject.